# How do i get selected radiobuttonlist in asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am using following code for a radiobuttonlist with default value of yes.

```
 <asp:RadioButtonList ID="RadioButtonList1" runat="server" onselectedindexchanged="radiobtnlist_SelectedIndexChanged">
    <asp:ListItem Selected="True">YES</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>NO</asp:ListItem>
 </asp:RadioButtonList>
```

Every time when the value of the radiobtnlist is changed an event is fired.I am using following c# code for selected index changed

```
protected void radiobtnlist_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //do work
}
```

Problem is that when radiobtnlist value is set as No and the selection is not changed but the selectedindex change event is fired and when radiobtnlist is set as Yes, the selectedindex change event is not fired.

I have to find the selection of radiobtnlist everytime before postback and if its value is changed then saved data in db but how to find the selected value of radiobtnlist with a default value on a ListItem.

Comment: Can you describe the problem in the next way: "What should happen", and "What actually happens"?

Comment: How to find selected value of ListItem in radiobtnlist_SelectedIndexChanged event.

Comment: I think you just need to set AutoPostBack="True", and .NET will do that for you.

Comment: adiobtnlist_SelectedIndexChanged event is not working when a default value is set.

Comment: Well, you asked if the `SelectedIndexChanged`.. it wasn't.

Comment: I might not understand what you are saying.  Do you mean you need to find the selected item on every postback?  Why can't you look at the items IsSelected Property?

Answer (score 0):

I think I get what you are saying.

The default answer is YES so this means that when a user wants YES to be selected, it is already selected hence they leave it alone. Because the RadioList value is left alone, no events are triggered.

Based on the code you provided I can see there is no "AutoPostBack" set. If this is the case, then I am assuming that you are triggering a postback via a submit button.

If you are triggering a postback via a submit button then you could put your logic in there. That way it will be triggered every time. E.g.:

```
protected void submit_click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    var answerIsYes = (radiobtnlist.SelectedIndex == 0);
    //store value to DB
}
```

You didn't specify if your form is going to be used for editing existing data. If it is, then it won't be efficient to be storing the value of the RadioList back to the database every postback. You need to consider how you will change it so that it only stores the value if the value CHANGES.